# Updating NAS distro from Debian 9 to 12 while preserving software raid

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm

I need to upgrade my pc used as nas from debian 9 to 12, but I would like to do a fresh installation rather than an upgrade.

My machine have:
**1 ssd for boot (sda)

2 hd raid 1 (sdb + sdc)

2 hd raid 1 (sdd + sde)**

I don't care about the user configuration, I can backup the `/etc` and re create manually the configs reading the old one and updating manually with nano on the updated default etc conf provided by debian 12 because lot of time passed and some syntax may have changed.

I've seen various topics talking about backup all the data, sadly I have no space and money to create an additional duplicate of all the drives. So I have to do the things correctly at the first try.

The first time I used the debian graphical installer in order to create the software raids so I'm unsure how to proceed.

**What could be the best approach?**

- Use the debian graphical installer again with the attached hard drives and let it detect them? (not sure this is the best choice)

or

- Nuke *sda* (the ssd with the /) and disconnect the *sdb*, *sdc*, *sdd*, *sde* hard drives. Backup some files like the `mdadm` and `fstab` configuration and re create it manually on the new installation? After editing that file and a reboot can everything work just fine? Can you help me determine what files could be needed and how to proceed in this case?

I haven't touched anything so I still have access to the nas as is in debian9 environment.
I want to plan the things slowly and safe.

Comment: Personally I'd remove the data drives and install them manually afterwards. It's definitely just software RAID, no LUKS encryption?

Comment: There's no reason I can see why you shouldn't let the installer try to find them. If you don't like what it's offering, bail out, disconnect them and try again

Comment: @ChrisDavies no encryption at all. Heh wondering if just copying the relevant configuration files and fstab could be enough for having them back online.

Comment: Maybe. If you've a spare usb stick I'd recommend backing up `/etc`

Comment: Oh I can do it but was asking what could be the relevant files in /etc needed for software raid.

Comment: `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` would be the most important one for typical software RAID. Also, keep copies of old `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` at hand, to remember the UID/GID numbers of any users and groups that own files on the RAIDs, and re-establish those users and groups right after the base install is complete, to minimize the chance of any inconvenient overlaps. And of course, the configuration of whichever network sharing protocols you are using - reconfiguring even a fairly simple set of fileshares without documentation can be a pain. (Don't ask me how I know...)

Comment: That's why I'm recommending the entirety of /etc. Better too much...